# Resize image to specific width and fix height

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to resize big images to have a width of 150 pixels and the height will be fixed.
and then save the image into a folder in my website.

examples: (width,height)
if I resize an image 300px*300px I will get a resized image of 150px*150px.
if I resize an image 450px*300px I will get a resized image of 150px*100px.

the point is that the ratio between width and height will be saved always keeping a width of 150 pixels.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this (not mine) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991587/how-can-i-crop-scale-user-images-so-i-can-display-fixed-sized-thumbnails-without)

```
private Bitmap ScaleImage(Image oldImage)
{
    double resizeFactor = 1;

    if (oldImage.Width > 150 || oldImage.Height > 150)
    {
        double widthFactor = Convert.ToDouble(oldImage.Width) / 150;
        double heightFactor = Convert.ToDouble(oldImage.Height) / 150;
        resizeFactor = Math.Max(widthFactor, heightFactor);

    }
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(oldImage.Width / resizeFactor);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(oldImage.Height / resizeFactor);
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, but again, not my solution, taken from someone else. All Kudo's to him and Google.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with a stylesheet. First, define the following style:

```
.thumb {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  width: expression(this.width > 150 ? "150px" : true);
  height: expression(this.height > 150 ? "150px" : true);
}
```

Then, add this style to your image tags, like so:

```
<img class="thumb" ...>
```

Do not include the height and width elements this time.

The first half of that style is for browsers that support the max-width and max-height properties -- Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari. The second half is a hack for IE, which doesn't.

Here is an Example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7Xsd/)